# how can we refesh list items after updating in dispForm?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

By clicking button in DispForm window I wrote some script for updating some list items. Here im facing two issues . 
One is , items are not updated until refreshing list page.
second is, DispForm window is not closing .

```
    function DoLogicalDelete()
   {

    var clientContext = null;
    var oList = null;
    var oListItem = null;
    var lstItmIsDeleted = null;


    var itmID = getQuerystring('ID');

    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web();


//    var currentListGUID = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
//   if (currentListGUID == null)
//    {
//       var listname = $(".s4-titletext h2 a:first").html(); //requires JQuery to get list name from ribbon breadcrumb
//alert('here1111'); 
//     return listname;
//    }


   var s = window.location.toString();
   var ss=s.split('Lists/')[1].split('/')[0];

     oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ss); 

     oListItem = oList.getItemById(itmID);                         // getting ID

     clientContext.load(oListItem,"Title", "IsDeleted");            // load items to oListItem



    oListItem.set_item('IsDeleted', true);
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),Function.createDelegate(this, 

this.onQueryFailed)); 
}



function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) 
{
 //   var lstItmTitle = null;
 //   lstItmTitle = oListItem.get_item('Title');      
 //   alert('This' + '\n' +lstItmTitle + ' has been successfully deleted!');

      alert('This item has been deleted successfully');


    //this.form.close();
     this.document.close();

//CloseAndRefresh(); 

}
```

Help me solve this guyz..
Thanks.

Comment: It will help if you can share your code.

Comment: See nadeen .. i just posted my code . Do u have any solution to close dispForm window??

Comment: I did not understand what is going on here.. Are you sent any solution to this Nadeen... Sorry I'm new to stackexchange.

Comment: Did you try window.close()

Comment: Yes nedeem.. its didn't work.

Comment: here document.reload(true) is working for reloading same window but no use to reload same window. here need to reload list page.

Comment: See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes .. I got answer finally...

1way:  //Commit/Refresh parent window on save button click

```
 window.frameElement.commitPopup();
```

2nd way:
You add the code to close the window after update the item . If you close the window, then update it, it will be not success.

```
window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the main list page then in the query string you have got a source query string. Read that and then reload the page. It will look something like this: `Source=http%3A%2F%2Faissp2013%3A111%2FLists%2FTasks%2FAllItems%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x01080099F4036E0B206641B772AFF7A91EAC6E`

Moreover, the way you are retrieving the list title is not a proper or fool proof way as you are manipulation the Url to get list title. However, the url and title of a list can be different. Suppose you create a list with Title "Projects". The Url will also have "Projects". But if you go again into list setting and change Title to "XYZ", the url will stay same i.e. "Projects", unless you then go into SharePoint Designer and change the Url of the list.

Comment: ya..thanks..perfect solution for list name... still i hav prob to find source querystring... can you please tell where I hav to find this..?

Comment: Go to item-> View Item and open it a new window. Notice how the url looks in the browser.

Comment: http://siteinfo-sp:9999/Lists/Projects/All%20Projectss%20%20Home%20Page.aspx could not find any content typeId here ?